# How do I undo desktop changes if I accidently moved folders/files around?

Tags: windows-8

I was cleaning my keyboard and accidently "sorted" the folders/files on my desktop. Is it possible to undo those changes?

Comment: Not easily, a system restore might work but I've never tried it for the reason you've described. Going forward you should save a screen-shot of your desktop and hide it somewhere for future reference if this happens again.

Comment: Yes;  Just arrange them again.

Comment: There is at least one program doing that (unfortunately I don't remember its name), but it needs snapshot of desktop made when icons were setted correctly.

Comment: Hi Julia, welcome to Superuser. It would be wise to mention details of your computer. Is it PC or Mac?

Answer (score 5):

For Microsoft Windows, desktop changes are not "saved" immediately.

*Open a command prompt and type:*

```
  taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
```

*After the desktop disappears type:*

```
  explorer
```

**Your desktop icons should now be restored to their original position.**

---

---

PICTURE INSTRUCTIONS:

3 easy ways to open a command prompt:

[image: Opening a Windows Command Prompt]

Type these commands to restore the desktop icons:

[image: Restore desktop position using these commands]

---

DETAILS:

- You must not wait too long to use this technique.
- You must NOT logout of Windows or do anything to exit Explorer normally.

This technique only works because it interrupts Windows opportunity to save the changes to the desktop in its normal manner.

You are essentially "crashing" the desktop program. If you wait too long, or exit the Windows desktop in a normal manner, Windows takes the opportunity to "save" your changes so that you can pick up where you left off.

---

WORD OF WARNING:

Ctrl-Z is ubiquitous in the world of computers for UNDO-ing human mistakes and experiments. Do not be tempted to use it for Windows interfaces.  Windows does not assume a human is trying to undo something they are looking at physically on the current screen.  Ctrl-Z in Windows will generally undo the last disk operation (such as deleting, renaming, or moving a file), even if that operation occurred 2 days ago, and that UNDO will be completely invisible to you. If you use Ctrl-Z with Windows, you will likely become confused why your important files keep disappearing.

Comment: You are a goddamn hero.

Answer (score -1):

Believe it or not, but the famouse CTRL-Z (Undo) even works in windows explorer.

As long as you don't hard-delete a file (shift-delete) you can **undo the last action** by pressing CTRL-Z. A move command will move it back, and a copy command will give a popup requesting if you want to delete the files you just copied.

EDIT: Disregard this post. CTRL-Z doesn't move back icons if their phyisical location on the disk hasn't changed. So no re-orientation changes.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to down vote that. She said 'sorted' not deleted. Hence CTRL+Z does not work.

Answer (score -2):

This answer is supposing you are using PC/Windows.

Windows by default, sorts in name. So if you had not specifically ordered it in a certain way, try right clicking on the desktop, sort > By Name.

Hope it helps

Comment: Who sorts their icons using a built-in option? Most people are more ordered than that. This also doesn't answer the OP's question. Assume the icons were not sorted, and they accidentally sorted them. You want to undo that, not sort them again.

Answer (score -2):

SOLUTION: Right-Click, Sort By, None.

Right-Click on the desktop, select Sort By, scroll to the top of the list and select None. All the files on the desktop should re-sort to your previous order.

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have "sort by none".

Answer (score -2):

download desktopOK (https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopOK), install it, rearrange your desktop icons manually, and immediately save the layout in the utility.  This won't undo your current problem, but it will in the future.  The utility is completely freeware, and was created by the author because Windows sometimes will rearrange your desktop icons if you unplug a monitor or connect by RDP.  I had almost given up on desktop icons altogether (I have 4 monitors, and rearranging the desktop was taking almost an hour a week), but desktopOK solved this Windows aggravation very effectively.  If you end up using desktopOK, I recommend making a donation to the software developer, even though the software never prompts you to. hope this helps, -David H, RN

Comment: I am going to consider this to be spam